# Why in a Chrome extension, the fetched text is parsed into a web page, and then the script in it is loaded?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am requesting a URL in the extension's options page. Although the content of this URL is a web page, but I read it as text at this time, Chrome actually actively downloads the script in the text content, which triggers the CSP.

1. Why does Chrome think about parsing text content into web pages and then loading scripts?
2. In addition, why use the commented sentence in the code to fetch, but the content obtained is blank? I can get the data through the simulated request tool, just fill in the URL without adding any request headers.

Thanks, I really don't understand why these two things happen.

```js
let url = "https://www.douyin.com/user/MS4wLjABAAAA6SPZyhEA5zRYJsmNsm1Xj5PW1cGRJXZ9jx7bX5p7SwXo-a2ByHwlHbfzEbjLeroO?showTab=like"
let resp = await fetch(url)
// let resp = await request(url, undefined, {credentials: "omit"})
let text = await resp.text()

return
```

[image]

Then I tried to fetch the URL in the Chrome console of the extension page and I got a CSP error too. So why parse the text into a web page and then load the script in it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com/1240091) that was dismissed by its developer as intentional behavior. Chrome prefetches resources (js scripts in your case) specified in the headers of the server response for the URL you fetch. Since extensions disallow remote js, these additional requests are automatically blocked.

The simple workaround is to exclude `html` from the default `Accept: */*` header:

```js
fetch(url, {headers: {accept: 'text/plain'}})
```

Note that the server may easily ignore it and still respond with the preload header, in which case you can use chrome.webRequest (ManifestV2) or chrome.declarativeNetRequest (ManifestV3/V2) to strip this header, usually it's `link`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it turned out to be related to the request header link.